# Custom attribute not getting created - Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.5 version. I'm trying to create custom attribute. I have followed following tutorials
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-learn/tutorials/backend-development/add-product-attribute.html?lang=en
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-how-to-create-product-custom-attribute-from-installer-in-custom-module/

Custom attribue is not getting created even after executing php **bin/magento setup:upgrade** command. Is there any change in process in newer version?
**php bin/magento setup:di:compile** also got executed without errors.

Comment: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/admin/custom-text-field-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

Delete your module from setup_module table and run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** again, also please do not use 'InstallData' as it is not recommended by Magento. Instead use 'patch'

[See here for patch](https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-product-attribute-programmatically-using-data-patch-magento-2/)

Comment: Getting following error
call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class \Vendor\Extention\Setup\Patch\Data\Addcustomdatapatch not found .. could someone please help me on this

Comment: You have to give your Namespace and module name in place of vendor\Extension